# Protractor - Jasmine . Perform some action only when a specific element is present.

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, jasmine, protractor

I have a window-box with two buttons 'add' and 'close'. I need to test below scenario:
When clicked on 'add' button it throws error and the window remains open. I need to click on 'close' button to proceed.

I used below code:

```
if(element(by.xpath("xpath_of_error_box")).isEnabled()) 
    {   
        element(by.xpath("xpath_of_close_button")).click();
    }
```

But it throws below error:

```
No element found using locator: By(xpath, xpath_of_error_box)
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, it seems that your xpath locator didn't match any element. And according to the additional clarification in the question you could try:

```
element(by.xpath("xpath_of_error_box")).isDisplayed().then(isDisplayed => {
    if (isDisplayed) {
    // do what you need when it is visible
    } else {
    // if not then proceed
    }
});
```

As it was pointed out, isEnabled might not be the proper method you should use in this case. If it seems that the element you try to find is always present in the dom, you might better try to check for its visibility using isDisplay instead.
An advice. It's not a good idea to use xpath locators in your tests, because this ties them to the html DOM structire of the web page you are observing. As we know, the UI happens to change often, which would make your tests to brake often as well. Although this is of cource a personal preference, it is such until you end up with tons of brocken tests after a single small change in the html.

Comment: Thanks for the above solution. It worked for me. And for your xpath suggestion if not xpath then what would you suggest?

Comment: @LovishJain I'm glad it helped. According to the xpath, IMO (and not just mine), it's better to be used css selectors wherever it's possible. When I'm the author of the code, I prefer to put properly crafted css marker classes in my components and use them in my tests. Of course, if I'm not careful, then I could easily end up with the same problem as with the xpath selectors. So as a rule - I don't overspecify the css selectors in the tests to avoid coupling with the DOM structure. Another problem is with 3rd party libraries which doesn't have appropriate classes. Then you may not avoid xpaths

Comment: It's OK to select by xpath elements in thrid party UI libraries when there aren't appropriate selectors. The dependent libraries are not changed or updated very often and as a rule, developers try to not introduce braking changes, so it's not such a harm :)

Comment: @Lovish Jain If the answer has helped you to solve the problem, would you consider to upvote?

Comment: I have marked the answer as correct. My upvote is not visible because I am new to stackoverflow and I need at least 15  reputations to upvote an answer. @factor5

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if an element is present you can use the following code:

```
if (element(by.xpath("yourXpath")).isPresent())
```

But your problem is not on your `if` code, your problem is that the xpath your are searching doesn't exist.

Comment: Maybe i am not clear in my question. Sorry for that. What i want is - If the element is present then click on that element and if the element is not present then proceed to the next step without throwing any error. Also when i use IsPresent() this element is always present and located even when the dialog box containing that element is not open. I am not sure if this is some feature of Angular applications

Comment: if (await element(by.xpath("yourXpath")).isPresent()){ 
//Do something
}

Is a promised, you can use Async function and await to resolve it.

That works really fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. `isEnabled()` and `isPresent()` returns promise (not boolean) and have to be resolved.
2. `isEnabled()` could be only used for `<button>`.
3. You can use XPath all the time, don't listen to anyone.

PS. Of course it would be glad to see your HTML to check the correctness of your XPath.

Comment: Maybe i am not clear in my question. Sorry for that. What i want is - If the element is present then click on that element and if the element is not present then proceed to the next step without throwing any error.

But when i use IsPresent() or isEnabled() and if the element is not present it throws error.

Is there any way to do that?